# list formatting: multiple mailto-links break code

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, json-formatting, send-email

When I use an **a** element in JSON to generate a mailto-link, everything works fine:

```
{
                    "elmType": "a",
                    "style": {
                      "position": "absolute",
                      "left": "20px",
                      "width": "40px",
                      "height": "40px",
                      "line-height": "40px",
                      "border-radius": "50%",
                      "text-align": "center",
                      "cursor": "pointer",
                      "text-decoration": "none"
                    },
                    "attributes": {
                      "iconName": "Mail",
                      "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary ms-fontWeight-semibold",
                      "href": "='mailto:' + [$Profil.email]",
                      "title": "='Eine Email an ' + [$Title] + ' schreiben'"
                    }
                  }
```

This code generates a clickable icon, which opens the mail-client with the email address provided by the people field **Profil**.
However, if I generate a second mailto-link with the same technique for a list entry, it seems to break the code and displays nothing. Also if I use **callto:** (to start a Teams call) instead of mailto: it doesn't work.

If I just use one of both linktypes the list element displays fine.

I figured out that it seems to be because of the **:** but can't find a way to get around it.
Using AST formatting didn't help either.

**EDIT:**

The *callto:* link, which cannot be used in a JSON format, can be replaced with a valid https-link according to [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-an-audio-or-audio-video-call) here. It needs to be in this format:

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=joe@contoso.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you putting them inside a `div` element?
I've taken your code and modified it slightly and it seems to be working for me. The only things I've done are wrapping the two `a` elements in a `div` and changing the `left` attribute from 20px to 40px so it isn't overlapping.

This works fine for `mailto:` links but according to the following, you cannot use `callto:` links. You can use `tel:` links but they have specific requirements.

> You can use column formatting to provide hyperlinks that go to other
> webpages, or start custom functionality. This functionality is limited
> to static links that can be parameterized with values from fields in
> the list. You can't use column formatting to output links to protocols
> other than http://, https://, mailto: or .
>
> tel: protocol only allows digits, *+# special characters and .-/()
> visual separators.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#create-clickable-actions

My working version of your code for reference:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
{
                    "elmType": "a",
                    "style": {
                      "position": "absolute",
                      "left": "20px",
                      "width": "40px",
                      "height": "40px",
                      "line-height": "40px",
                      "border-radius": "50%",
                      "text-align": "center",
                      "cursor": "pointer",
                      "text-decoration": "none"
                    },
                    "attributes": {
                      "iconName": "Mail",
                      "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary ms-fontWeight-semibold",
                      "href": "='mailto:' + [$Profil.email]",
                      "title": "='Eine Email an ' + [$Title] + ' schreiben'"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "elmType": "a",
                    "style": {
                      "position": "absolute",
                      "left": "40px",
                      "width": "40px",
                      "height": "40px",
                      "line-height": "40px",
                      "border-radius": "50%",
                      "text-align": "center",
                      "cursor": "pointer",
                      "text-decoration": "none"
                    },
                    "attributes": {
                      "iconName": "Mail",
                      "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary ms-fontWeight-semibold",
                      "href": "='mailto:' + [$Profil.email]",
                      "title": "='Eine Email an ' + [$Title] + ' schreiben'"
                    }
                  }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thx for the clarification. So I guess the callto link was the problem... Sad that MSFT doesn't support their own programs.

Comment: I found a solution for the callto-link and added it to my question